# Cannot open file in resources directory

Tags: c++, qt, file-io, resources

I've tested every natural iteration that I can imagine right now but still can not successfully open a file with a QFile object.  I've also tested placing the file in the ./resources directory and in the directory with the source file.

I've cleaned my project in between each test and restarted Qt Creator as well.  I've also deleted my *.pro.user project configuration file and tested with new versions of that.

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
...
//QFile input_file("./resources/testfile.txt");
//QFile input_file("qrc:/10_graph.txt");
//QFile input_file("testfile.txt");
QFile input_file(":/testfile.txt");
if (!input_file.exists()) {
  qDebug() << "File does NOT exist";
  exit(11);
}
```

[image]

## Qt Creator >> About

Qt Creator 3.1.1 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.2.1 (Clang 5.0 (Apple), 64 bit)

Comment: Put your `testfile.txt` into the same directory with your executable and try `QFile input_file("testfile.txt");`

Comment: Can you specify which directory is the one with my executable.  I've attached an image of where I've placed my source.  I don't see how it should be more complicated than what I've got.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't find resource file and I run `Build -> Run qmake` in order to regenerate Makefile of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a resource file to your project and add the `testfile.txt` to the resources. After that you can access the file from resources by :

```
QFile input_file(":/testfile.txt");
```

If you add a prefix to the resources it can be accessed by :

```
QFile file(":/somePrefix/new.txt");
```

If you put the file in a folder alongside the source directory and add it to the resources, you can access it by :

```
QFile file(":/folderName/new.txt");
```

Comment: How the heck am I supposed to 'add a resource file to the project'?  You can see by the image that I've placed testfile.txt in the resources directory within the source code directory.

Comment: right click on the project in the project pane and choose: Add New>Qt>Qt Resource file. Enter a name for the resource file. Click next and finish. Now you can open the resource file, add a prefix and then add the file.

Comment: That was the crux of the problem -- resource file creation in Qt.  Thanks Nejat.